# Mysqli sum the last five data

Tags: php, mysql

Please I have a table with 10 rows and I will like to sum the first five data.

```
----------
data
----------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and I want the result to be 1+2+3+4+5 = 15

Comment: That looks like you're summing the ___first___ 5 rows, not the last 5.... how do you identify which are the last?

Comment: @MarkBaker i mean sum the first 5 rows

Answer (score 1):

SQL Query (when data is not sorted, and you don't require it to be):

```
SELECT sum(data) 
FROM (SELECT data
      FROM myTable
      LIMIT 5
) AS subquery;
```

SQL Query (when data is not sorted, but you require it to be):

```
SELECT sum(data) 
FROM (SELECT data
      FROM myTable
      ORDER BY data ASC
      LIMIT 5
) AS subquery;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e51db/2

Comment: The first query returns the sum of all data, not only the first 5, and returns 55. However, the second query, which has the subquery in it works just fine and return 15.

Comment: @RasmusRosengren I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query, use `limit` like `LIMIT 0,5` which will limit the results of the table to only the first 5 rows. and `sum` it.

So do :

```
SELECT sum(your_column) from `your_table` LIMIT 0,5
```

If this doesn't help, show how you are pulling the data from MySQL.